# Using session-scoped object in singleton in Spring

Tags: spring, session-scope

I have a problem with one of my beans. I have a bean, which has a singleton scope and second bean which has session scope.

I'm using java based config in my spring app, I added proxy mode to my session scope bean, but it throws exception when I'm tryign to use that (session scoped) bean:

> Method threw 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' exception. Cannot evaluate `my-bean-full-name$$EnhanceBySpringCGLIB#ID.toString()`

From what I have read here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection-proxies

I thought that only thing which I have to do is to add

```
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
```

to my bean class (which also has @Component annotation and it is scanned by Spring)

Comment: share your code snippet?

Comment: does the session scoped bean implement an interface? If not let it implement and perhaps make it serializable

Comment: Thanks for the response.
@HankLapidez I will check your suggestion

Comment: @CHowdappaM
What snippet? The only thing which i use here is the Scope annotation. Tehn I use Autwired on field to inject my bean. I also use componentScan annotation to scan package with my bean. I don't use any code more to reach my goal

Comment: @HankLapidez it didn't helped. I left annotations on implementation class

Answer (score 2):

The thing which I was missing was this line in my web app initializer:

```
    servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
```

After that, bean has been injected